# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & when passing list/array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am new to JavaScript. I am using Flask and Python, and the Flask template uses Jinja template library to render the template. I get my array through an API call.
My array looks like this :

```
    array = [{
        country: 'Macediona', 
        city: ['Skopje','Ohrid', 'Bitola']
        }, {
        country: 'Switzerland', 
        city: ['Bazel', 'Zurich', 'Zeneva']
        }, {
        country: 'Srbia', 
        city: ['Nis', 'Belgrad']
        }];
```

I can pass this array in the HTML template with {{ array }} and I can also do the same in Javascript according to Flask documentation.

But when I do in Javascript:

```
var list = {{ array }}
```

I have error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &.
Debugging from the console I see that the list is passed with additional "things" before and after the key and values.

```
    array = [{
        &#39;country&#39;: '&#39;Macediona&#39;', 
        ....
```

How can I get clean array in Javascript?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Can you show us  the code, where the error occurs?

Comment: If I do: var list = {% raw %}{{ array }}{% endraw %} I have another error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For safety reasons Jinja is escaping the html in your code.
`&#39;` is the html code for an `'`

Information about jinja's html escaping can be found here:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#html-escaping

> When automatic escaping is enabled, everything is escaped by default except for values explicitly marked as safe.

So to prevent Jinja from escaping your code you can use Jinja's built in filters.
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#safe
To mark your code as safe use the `safe` filter.

```
var list = {{ array | safe }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem! xD

Comment: @mitevva_t glad to help. Please accept the answer to mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the string

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
return $('<div>').html(html).text();
```

}

decodeHtml("[{&#3 9;country': '&#3 9;Macediona&#3 9;'}]") will give

```
    "[{'country': ''Macediona''}]"
```